# How do I programatically get the jOOQ Table of a Hibernate model?

Tags: java, hibernate, jooq

I am using Hibernate + jOOQ + PostgreSQL.

I have a Hibernate model as follows:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

  public UUID id;
  public String email;
  public Date createdAt;

}
```

I would like to programatically get the jOOQ Table object for this model.

I've done this by getting all the tables from `jooq.meta().getTables()` and then filtering through those.. But that's inefficient and cumbersome.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Without using the code generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jOOQ code generator has a `JPADatabase` that you can configure as a meta data source. It will then use Hibernate behind the scenes to publish your entities into an in-memory H2 database, and reverse engineer that again using standard code generation functionality. This way, you can keep your entities and your jOOQ code in sync

More details here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa